# jQuery change <span> into <label> and add for="" with previous <input> id

Tags: jquery, html, input, label

I have some jQuery to turn selected spans into labels.

The problem I have now is that I need to add in the for="" so that it works as a button (I'm using radio buttons with the input hidden so it's just a box - therefore the label needs to have the id of the input in order to work). I know I need to create a variable but I'm not sure how to write it.

What I need (and correct me if I'm wrong) is a variable that creates the `<label>` tag + for="" with the id of the previous input within the "".

Now these radio buttons are brought in with a module though the CMS I'm using so I can't target the id name itself as its different every time and generated by the CMS. So the js needs to target the 'previous/parent' input tag.

So this is what I need the final code to look like after the js has run:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="SML">
   <label for="radio1">Small</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="MED">
   <label for="radio2">Meduim</label >
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="LRG">
   <label for="radio3">Large</label >
</div>
```

Help please!

```js
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.each($(".wrapper span"), function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<label>" + $(this).text() + "</label>");
    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
input[type=radio] {
    display:none; 
    margin:10px;
}

input[type=radio] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border-color:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#BDBDBD;
 cursor:pointer;

}

input[type=radio]:checked + label { 
   background-image: none;
    background-color:#EBE300;
 color:#454545;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
 <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="SML">
       <span>Small</span>
 <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="MED">
       <span>Meduim</span>
 <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="LRG">
       <span>Large</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you could use attributes (like `id`,`class`) to store the `for` data

Answer (score 1):

Just change the js to

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery.each($(".wrapper span"), function() {
    var input_id = $(this).prev().attr("id");
    $(this).replaceWith("<label for='"+input_id+"'>" + $(this).text() + "</label>");
    });
  });
```

which will get the id of the previous node and add it to label "for" attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
jQuery.each($(".wrapper span"), function() {
      var id = "radio"+i;
      $(this).replaceWith("<label for='radio"+id+"'> " + $(this).text() + "</label>");
      i++;
   });
});
</script>
```

Remember the iteration function ;)